# SmartCard ISO7816 ACOS6 Pin Protected File?

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I need a protect smartcard EF files with PIN. Please guide me?

CARD Operating system is ACOS
CARD Size:64KByte
CARD Protocol: ISO7816 T0
Here is the my sample code

Best Regars

```
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
; Card Security
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
; Clear card
80 30 00 00 00 (90 00)

; Reset card
[RST] [0]

; Create Master File
00 E0 00 00 1E 62 1C 82 01 3F 83 02 3F 00 8A 01 01 8C 08 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 8D 02 00 00 87 02 00 00 (90 00)

; Create DF, ID = "DF 01", DF Long Name = "TEST File 01"
00 E0 00 00 2C 62 2A 82 01 38 83 02 DF 01 84 0C 54 45 53 54 20 46 49 4C 45 20 30 31 8A 01 01 8C 08 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 8D 02 00 00 87 02 00 00 (90 00)

; Select "TEST FILE 01"
00 A4 04 00 0C 54 45 53 54 20 46 49 4C 45 20 30 31 (61 XX)
;61 2E Issue GET RESPONESE with P3 = 2E to retrieve data

; Create PIN File
00 E0 00 00 1D 62 1B 82 05 0C 00 00 08 03 83 02 EF 01 88 01 01 8A 01 01 8C 08 7F 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 (90 00)

; Create Key File
00 E0 00 00 1D 62 1B 82 05 0C 00 00 16 06 83 02 EF 02 88 01 02 8A 01 01 8C 08 7F 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 (90 00)

; Select PIN File
00 A4 00 00 02 EF 01 (61 XX)
;Issue GET RESPONSE with P3 = 20

; Append PIN Record 1 
00 E2 00 00 08 81 FF 11 11 11 11 11 11 (90 00)

; Select Key File
00 A4 00 00 02 EF 02 (61 XX)
;Issue GET RESPONSE with P3 = 20

; Append Card Key
00 E2 00 00 15 81 06 FF FF 00 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 (90 00)


;Select File By File ID DF 01
00 A4 00 00 02 DF 01 (61 XX)
;61 2E Issue GET RESPONESE with P3 = 2E to retrieve data


;Create TrasnParent File (FF01)
00 E0 00 00 1D 62 1B 80 02 04 00 82 01 01 83 02 FF 01 88 01 01 8A 01 01 8C 08 7F 00 00 00 00 FF 01 (90 00) 

**and the when update file without PIN permission updated! :(**

**> Update Binary
> 00 D6 00 00 04 11 22 33 44
< 90 00**
```

and when update file without enter PIN. File updated without PIN :(

```
;Update Binary
00 D6 00 00 04 11 22 33 44
90 00
```

Comment: Your "Create transparent file" command seems truncated, the tlv structure is violated for the 8C data object, which states 8 bytes are following, but only 7 are given.

Comment: 00 E0 00 00 1D 62 1B 80 02 04 00 82 01 01 83 02 FF 01 88 01 01 8A 01 01 8C 08 7F 00 00 00 00 FF 01 00  correct?
What is full cycle for activate security. Just file Activation is enough for Test PIN or Card?  Actually can yo give simple code for PInNprotected file? @guidot